# Pexels API Python Request

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I tried doing API request with Python for Pexels, but get authentication error.  Documentation [link](https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/?) Here is my code:

```
import requests
video_base_url = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search'
api_key = 'my_key'
my_obj = {'Authorization':api_key, 'query':'Stock market'}
x = requests.get(video_base_url,data = my_obj)
print(x.text)
```

But I get "error": "Authorization field missing". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are sending the authorization in the body of the request

You need to send it in the header

```
r = requests.get(video_base_url, headers = {'Authorization': api_key}, data = my_obj)
```